# Adding User Defined data

Tags: c#

First thing I want to say is that this is for my homework.  I am not looking for the answer just assistance in figuring out what I am doing wrong.  This is my fist programming class and up till this point I have been doing great.  Now all of a sudden I am lost.

The Question:
Create an application that lets the user enter the monthly costs of the following expenses incurred from operating his or her automobile:  Loan payment, insurance, gas, oil, tires, and maintenance.  The program should then display the total monthly cost of these expenses and the total annual cost of these expenses.

This is what I have built:

private void totalMonthlyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        decimal loan;        // Monthly cost of loan
        decimal insurance;   // Monthly insurance cost
        decimal gas;         // Monthly gas cost
        decimal oil;         // Monthly oil cost
        decimal tires;       // Monthly tire cost
        decimal maintenance; // Monthly maintenance cost
        decimal monthlyCost; // Monthly total cost

        // Get the loan amount.
        loan = decimal.Parse(loanTextBox.Text);
        // Get the insurance amount.
        insurance = decimal.Parse(insTextBox.Text);
        // Get the gas amount.
        gas = decimal.Parse(gasTextBox.Text);
        // Get the oil amount.
        oil = decimal.Parse(oilTextBox.Text);
        // get the tires amount.
        tires = decimal.Parse(tiresTextBox.Text);
        // Get the maintenance amount.
        maintenance = decimal.Parse(mainTextBox.Text);
        // determine the monthly cost.
        monthlyCost = decimal.Parse(totalMonthlyLabel.Text);

        // Calculate monthly cost.
        monthlyCost = loan + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance;

        // Display the monthlyCost in the correct control.
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.  Again I do not want the answer just some pointers of if I'm heading in the right direction, if I am completely off, where to go next etc.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: The best tip I can give a starter is reduce the amount of comments you write. Your vars\methods should be clear enough. 
Where is your problem? You want to insert the total monthly cost into a textbox?

Comment: monthlyCost should not be parsed since this is the variable you want in the end. Once you do the adition just display the result(monthlyCost) in a MessageBox or so. Do not forget to use the .ToString() method.

Comment: Your code seems fine. If you want to convert the `monthlyCost` decimal variable into `String`, use `monthlyCost.ToString()` and insert it to the correct textbox

Comment: Yes the way I have it built is the user will enter there information into the textboxes and then the answer will populate into a label.  Up to the point above I have no errors that show, however when I try to tell the program where to display the monthlyCost everything I put in there causes an error.

Comment: Did you include the how you "try to tell the program where to display"? I don't see that part. Feel free to [edit] that in

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but check out the TryParse methods on the numeric types -- will save you grief when the user enters junk in input controls.

Comment: Commented with a code that should work properly with a `try catch` statement. Will prevent program crashes too

Comment: don't add tags to your question title..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I removed a variable because that variable does not read the value it just has to display the value.

```
        decimal loan;        // Monthly cost of loan
        decimal insurance;   // Monthly insurance cost
        decimal gas;         // Monthly gas cost
        decimal oil;         // Monthly oil cost
        decimal tires;       // Monthly tire cost
        decimal maintenance; // Monthly maintenance cost
        decimal monthlyCost; // Monthly total cost

        // Get the loan amount.
        loan = decimal.Parse(loanTextBox.Text);
        // Get the insurance amount.
        insurance = decimal.Parse(insTextBox.Text);
        // Get the gas amount.
        gas = decimal.Parse(gasTextBox.Text);
        // Get the oil amount.
        oil = decimal.Parse(oilTextBox.Text);
        // get the tires amount.
        tires = decimal.Parse(tiresTextBox.Text);
        // Get the maintenance amount.
        maintenance = decimal.Parse(mainTextBox.Text);
        // determine the monthly cost.


        // Calculate monthly cost.
        monthlyCost = loan + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance;
        totalMonthlyLabel.Text = monthlyCost.ToString();
```

Comment: You guys rock!  Thank you all I was forgetting about was the ToString part.  How I missed that I do not know.  I have completed this project, including the annual part which I was then able to complete on my own.  Thank you to everyone who helped with this as I had been stressing over this the past couple days.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way that I can think of right now:

```
decimal loan;        // Monthly cost of loan
decimal insurance;   // Monthly insurance cost
decimal gas;         // Monthly gas cost
decimal oil;         // Monthly oil cost
decimal tires;       // Monthly tire cost
decimal maintenance; // Monthly maintenance cost
decimal monthlyCost; // Monthly total cost

try
{
    loan = decimal.Parse(loanTextBox.Text);
    insurance = decimal.Parse(insTextBox.Text);
    gas = decimal.Parse(gasTextBox.Text);
    oil = decimal.Parse(oilTextBox.Text);
    tires = decimal.Parse(tiresTextBox.Text);
    maintenance = decimal.Parse(mainTextBox.Text);
    monthlyCost = loan + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance;
    TotalMonthlyLabel.Text = monthlyCost.ToString();// Display the monthlyCost in the correct control.
}
catch { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get different type of monthly expenses from your user (that will be your input). Then your program is supposed to perform some calculations on that input in order to get some output (i.e. `monthlyCost` in your case). You don't have to get `monthlyCost` from your user.